# Wrong path return by a FileField in Django

Tags: django, filefield

I've got a FileField with the following `upload_to` option:

```
def get_file_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('rapports/rapports_journaliers', filename)

class ListPCA(models.Model): 
    pdf_file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path)
```

My files are properly saved in `<MEDIA_ROOT>/rapports/rapports_journaliers/<filename>`

but the path returned by

```
list_pca_instance.pdf_file.path
```

is wrong:

```
<MEDIA_ROOT>/<filename>
```

Anybody can help?

Thanks

Comment: What is stored in the database for `pdf_file`?

Comment: I get <FieldFile: f63fc14a-26a1-4a24-a9b8-8338ac1f5e88.pdf>, which means that only the filename is saved, without the path `rapports/rapports_journaliers/` before. That's what I don't understand since the file are saved at the right path...

Comment: have you tried adding a trailing slash? i.e. `os.path.join('rapports/rapports_journaliers/', filename)`